# MessageResources weird behaviour

Tags: java, jsp, internationalization, struts, struts-1

I have a web application. For multilanguage purpose I use java struts 1.3 with `MessageResources`. The default language is `italian` (`MessageResources.properties`) and the second language is `english` (`MessageResources_en.properties`).

in `struts-config.xml`:

```
<!--Message Resources  -->
<message-resources parameter="MessageResources" />
```

in my `index.jsp`:

```
<% String language = request.getLocale().getLanguage(); %>
        var lang = '<%=language%>';
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/language.js"></script>
```

in `js/language.js`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var browser = null;
    var val = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    if(val.indexOf("firefox") > -1) browser = 'FIREFOX';
    else if(val.indexOf("msie") > -1) browser = 'IE';
    else if(val.indexOf("chrome") > -1) browser = 'CHROME'; 
            
    $.ajax({
        url:"SetDefaultLanguage.do", 
        data: "isolingua="+lang+"&browser="+browser+"&val="+val,
        success: function (response) {}
        });
});
```

in `SetDefaultLanguage.java`:

```
//parametro del browser
if(request.getParameter("isolingua") != null)
{
    isolingua = request.getParameter("isolingua");
            
    switch (isolingua) 
    {
        case "en":
            request.getSession().setAttribute("lingua", 2);
            Locale.setDefault(Locale.ENGLISH);
            request.getSession().setAttribute(Globals.LOCALE_KEY, Locale.ENGLISH);
            System.out.println("CASE EN: "+Locale.getDefault()+" - "+request.getSession().getAttribute(Globals.LOCALE_KEY));
            break;
        
        case "it":
            request.getSession().setAttribute("lingua", 1);
            Locale.setDefault(Locale.ITALIAN);
            request.getSession().setAttribute(Globals.LOCALE_KEY, Locale.ITALIAN);
            System.out.println("CASE IT: "+Locale.getDefault()+" - "+request.getSession().getAttribute(Globals.LOCALE_KEY));
            break;
                    
        default:
            request.getSession().setAttribute("lingua", 1);
            Locale.setDefault(Locale.ITALIAN);
            request.getSession().setAttribute(Globals.LOCALE_KEY, Locale.ITALIAN);
            System.out.println("CASE DEFAULT: "+Locale.getDefault()+" - "+request.getSession().getAttribute(Globals.LOCALE_KEY));
            break;
    }
            
}
```

setting as browser language "Italian" it prints always CASE IT: it - it
but here it is the strange behavior: my index, registration or retrieve password pages can be

- all italian
- index and retrieve password italian and registration in english
- all in italian and just some words of retrieve password and registration in english
- ...
  when I restart tomcat it re-shows all the pages in italian

other info:

- after the login the application seems to be safe from this strange problem
- The application is hosted in a virtual server with english OS
- When I try the application on my local pc (with italian OS) this problem doesn't occur
- `request.getSession().setAttribute("lingua", <int>)` is used in servlets to retrieve the information into the db in the correct language; this always works correctly.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you use  `Locale.setDefault()` What the doc says:

> Sets the default locale for this instance of the Java Virtual Machine.
>   ...
>   Since changing the default locale may affect many different areas
>        of functionality, this method should only be used if the caller
>        is prepared to reinitialize locale-sensitive code running
>        within the same Java Virtual Machine.

Usually setting a session attribute `Globals.LOCALE_KEY` enough to change a locale and you can use the code to save a locale

```
// Extract attributes we will need
HttpSession session = request.getSession();

// Get locale from request, if any
Locale locale = request.getLocale();

// If supplied, set Locale based on request parameter        
String language = request.getParameter("isolingua");

if (language != null && language.length() > 0) {
  switch (language) {
    case "en":
      locale = Locale.ENGLISH;
      session.setAttribute("lingua", 2);
      break;
    default:
      locale = Locale.ITALIAN;
      session.setAttribute("lingua", 1);
      break;
  }
}

//Save locale
session.setAttribute(Globals.LOCALE_KEY, locale);
```

Comment: Unfortunatey after a couple days of good behaviour with your advice, I re-deployed my application and I've got the same problem again (deploy + Tomcat restart).

Comment: Do you have any other applications deployed on that Tomcat?

Comment: I just noticed that if I access to the application for the first time with browser in english, than the following accesses with italian browser I see all english, otherwise first access with italian brawser than the following accesses work fine (at least the first day...than I've got the same problems I mentioned in my main question)

Comment: @RomanC: In the webapp there isn't any Locale.setDefault(), the demo and the real webapp have the same code, moreover on a webserver clone, we have more than two other applications deployed and this issue doesn't happen that is a mix of italian and english words. Where could be the "trick"?

Answer (score 0):

Would you mind, try implementing it with a this following logic:

```
if (request.getParameter("isolingua") != null) { // check to avoid null pointer excptn.
  if (request.getParameter("isolingua").equals("en")) {    
    // set english locale    
  }
  else {    
    // set italian locale (our default)    
  }
}
```

I am sure, it wont land you in a pool of abnormal/unexpected cases.